# Why is a repository still in /etc/apt/sources.list.d after removing it with add-apt-repository --remove?

Tags: 12.04, ppa

I am trying to remove a repository in 12.04, like so

```
sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:cassou/emacs
sudo apt-get update
```

but when I run the command

```
ls /etc/apt/sources.list.d
```

I get the name of ppa mentioned in the list

```
cassou-emacs-precise.list
cassou-emacs-precise.list.save
```

Why so?

Comment: What are the contents of `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/cassou-emacs-precise.list`? The lines are probably commented out. You can also just delete the files manually by the way.

Comment: @terdon Ok, the file looks empty. But it was not deleted automatically.

Answer (score 4):

add-apt-repository --remove doesn't actually remove the repository but disables it. If you want to remove the repository along with any package it may have installed you can by using ppa-purge:

```
sudo ppa-purge ppa:cassou/emacs
```

http://www.webupd8.org/2012/11/install-ppa-purge-with-multi-arch.html

**NOTE:** This will downgrade any packages you might have installed from the PPA to the version available in the main repositories. As explained in `man ppa-purge`:

```
NAME
   ppa-purge - disables a PPA and reverts to official packages
```

Comment: ppa-purge does more than that it is - command line tool that downgrades all the packages installed from a PPA to the versions available in the official Ubuntu repositories.

Comment: @GauravAgarwal surely that will only happen if the tools in question are available in both?

Comment: @terdon Yes, for the reason you mentioned, this cannot be considered the answer to the problem.

Answer (score 2):

The repositories have been removed, if you check the contents of those files, you will find them empty. I don't know why they were not removed and I would call that a bug in `add-apt-repository` unless empty files are removed by default on reboot or similar.

In any case, for future reference, you can always simply delete the files manually:

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/cassou-emacs-precise.list*
sudo apt-get update
```

Comment: It does not remove even after restart. Do we need to file a bug report on add-apt-repository?